# Select datalist value on input change and populate the form using jQuery javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to do autocomplete, when input is changed and an option is selected from the datalist, then I want the form and text field to be populated with selected value/text from the datalist.
I tried many options from similar questions here on stackexchange, but not able to make it work.

Help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#UserCity').on('input', function() {
    var str = "";
    console.log($(this).val());
    $("#UserCitySelect").on('select', function() {
      str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    str = $("#UserCitySelect option:selected").text()
    console.log(str);
    document.getElementById("selected").text = str;
    document.getElementById("selecteddiv").innerHTML = str;
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="UserCity" id="UserCity" label="User City" max_length="25" list="UserCitySelect" required="">

<p id="selected"><p>
<div id="selecteddiv"><div>

<datalist id="UserCitySelect">
    <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: console.log($(this).val()); ?

Comment: @The_Death_Raw modified the question with this. It catches the city name. but doesn't get assigned to `str` and not getting populate in `p` or `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:selected` does not work on `datalist` options, as one datalist can provide suggestions for multiple inputs. If two different inputs contain two different suggestions from the list, which would be the selected one?

you can check the value of the input on change with event of input text and assign the value in `div` with the id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='UserCity']").on('input', function(e){
     var selectedVal = $(this).val();
     document.getElementById("selected").innerHTML = selectedVal ;
     document.getElementById("selecteddiv").innerHTML = selectedVal ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="UserCity" id="UserCity" label="User City" max_length="25" list="UserCitySelect" required="">
<datalist id="UserCitySelect">
    <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="Chicago">Chicago</option>
</datalist>
<p id="selected"></p>
<div id="selecteddiv"><div>
```